# Show all the Users that worked on a project and sum the hours

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| User | Actual | Project |
+------+--------+---------+
| A    | 5      | ProjA   |
| A    | 8      | ProjA   |
| B    | 3      | ProjA   |
| C    | 2      | ProjA   |
| B    | 8      | ProjB   |
| B    | 8      | ProjB   |
+------+--------+---------+
```

My query is like this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT User, 
 SUM(Actual) AS Actual
 FROM Table
 Where Project = "ProjA" AND
 User = "A"
```

The result is

```
+------+--------+
| User | Actual |
+------+--------+
| A    | 13     |
+------+--------+
```

What I would like to achieve is for the query to show all the Users that worked on that project and then the sum of the Actual per employee and then if possible get the total of all the Actual, something like this:

```
+------+--------+
| User | Actual |
+------+--------+
| A    | 13     |
| B    | 3      |
| C    | 2      |
+------+--------+

+-------+----+
| Total | 18 |
+-------+----+
```

How should I do this? I tried removing the `User = "A"` in the where clause but that really didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user,
     SUM(actual) as actual
FROM `table`
Where Project = "ProjA"
GROUP BY user
WITH ROLLUP
```

`WITH ROLLUP` will give you a total row with user value of NULL.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60a3d/4)

if you want 'Total' returned instead of NULL you can use this

```
SELECT if(User is NULL,'Total',User) as User,
     SUM(Actual) as Actual
FROM `table`
Where Project = "ProjA"
GROUP BY user
WITH ROLLUP
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60a3d/5)

`WITH ROLLUP` is pretty sweet in that it provides summary lines for all your GROUP BY so that if you wanted to drop the `WHERE Project = "ProjA"` and do summaries for each project and all projects you can do something like below.

```
SELECT IF(Project IS NULL,'All Projects',Project) as Project,
       IF(User IS NULL,'Total',User) as User,
     SUM(Actual) as Actual
FROM `table`
GROUP BY Project,User
WITH ROLLUP
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60a3d/11)

### updated

If you just want the total of ProjA you can do

```
SELECT 'Total' as User,SUM(Actual) as Actual
FROM `table`
WHERE Project = "ProjA"
```

or if you want to just select the total row from the ROLLUP you can do this (not sure why you want to but here it is)

```
SELECT User,Actual FROM
(SELECT if(User is NULL,'Total',User) as User,
     SUM(Actual) as Actual
FROM `table`
Where Project = 'ProjA'
GROUP BY User
WITH ROLLUP
 )T
WHERE User = 'Total'
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60a3d/16)

Comment: Hi, question again, I used the query you suggested, but I was wondering what if I want to return just the total value, how should the query be?

Comment: just the total would be a simple SUM function like `SELECT SUM(Actual) as Actual FROM `table` WHERE Project = "ProjA"`

Comment: I mean I want to select the value of the Total when you used the ROLLUP, I want to select the `| Total | 18 |`

Comment: see updated section of my answer, at bottom there's a query that returns the 'Total' row from the ROLLUP it's the same result as the simple SUM()